# Passing terminal file argument into python script

Tags: python, terminal

I have a file called `students.csv` that I am trying to pass into a python script `s1.py`. On the command line I type `python3 s1.py students.csv`, however I get the error

```
File "s1.py", line 7, in <module>
    with open(file, 'r') as studentGrades:
TypeError: invalid file: ['s1.py', 'students.csv']
```

Here is the code in s1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env Python3

import sys

file = sys.argv

with open(file, 'r') as studentGrades:
        for line in studentGrades:
                print(line)
```

How do I pass in this file correctly so I can use it in my python script?

Answer (score 3):

Do `file = sys.argv[1]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @EricWang said, you can do `file = sys.argv[1]` to get the filename if it was included. However, there are a number of edge cases this doesn't account for:

- This code will fail if the user forgets to type the argument
- This code will fail if you have other arguments and the user doesn't type them in in a specific order
- This code will fail if the argument isn't a valid filename or the file doesn't exist.

To get around these, my suggestion is that you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html). This will enable you to name your arguments, allowing the user to enter them in any order. It has validation code, so you can make sure that the filename they entered is an actual file. It also has the concept of "required arguments" so if your user forgets to enter them then you can specify a handy error message to inform them how <strike>dumb</strike> misguided they are.